# "after the Great War's rude interruption"

Tags: meaning

> In 1927, after the Great War's rude interruption, Uhde resides in nearby Chantilly and tracks Séraphine down, buying her work and showering her with brushes and materials.

[Source](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2009/nov/29/seraphine-review).

How do you understand the formulation

> In 1927, after the Great War's **rude** **interruption**. The end of World War I was after all in 1918.

So to use the word *interruption* seems to me odd. And moreover, I am puzzled by the adjective *rude* which indicates that the interruption of the war should be something bad or negative.

Comment: IMO, the 'interruption' doesn't mean an interruption of the war. It sounds more like the war had interrupted something else.

Comment: Yes, you are probaly right. The Great War something interrupted in the lives of protagonists of the movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can find the answer in earlier paragraphs.

> Uhde (played by German actor Ulrich Tukur, who appears as the Baron in Michael Haneke's The White Ribbon) encourages Séraphine, promising her great things. "You have gold in your hands," he convinces her.
>
> When the German army rumbles into town, Provost shows Séraphine scraping away at her canvas, her hymns replaced by the thunder of mortars while Uhde, the "dirty German", is forced to flee.

So the great war seperated Séraphine and Uhde interrupting their relationship.

"Great War's rude interruption" in this context means the interruption caused by the great war, not the interruption of the great war.

As to the date it doesn't surprise me that it took a decade for Uhde to track down Séraphine. War has a habit of breaking up the normal order of society and forcing people to flee their previous lives.